# Questions about the Proof of Existence and Uniqueness of Solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading the Chapter 1.2 from the book *"Ordinary Differential Equation"* by Arnold, where it states the theorem:

> [image: Existence and Uniqueness of Solutions]

And the book first provides a brief proof with a problem: *"Find the gap in this proof"*

> [image: A brief Proof]

My first question is that: What does it mean by the gap in this proof? Does it mean the uniqueness of the solution?

After that, it gives a proof of uniqueness:

> [image: Proof of uniqueness 1]
>
> [image: Proof of uniqueness 2]

And in the second picture, I wonder what does it mean by the sentence I highlighted, and why it says *"Consequently ..."* .

Those may be some dumb questions, please not be mad at me. Thanks for any help and hint in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first question: The gap in this proof is that the uniqueness is only proved for the case that $x_0$ is no equilibrium position, i. e., $v(x_0) \neq 0$. The uniqueness in the case $v(x_0) \neq 0$ follows from the results described in chapter 1.

So what remains to show is the uniqueness for the case $x_0 = 0$. Note the following: It is already shown that their $\textit{exists}$ a solution through the given initial condition which is constant. In order to prove the uniqueness, it suffices to show that a solution, which also satisfies the initial condition, is constant.

So what he therefore does is the following: He supposes $\varphi(t_0) = x_0 = 0$ and $\varphi(t_1) = x_1 \neq 0$. Then he proves that this leads to a contradiction, i. e., $\vert t_2 - t_1 \vert$ is larger than any preassigned number ($t_2$ defined as in the text). Since this is a contradiction, the yellow marked sentence means: $\varphi(t_1) \neq 0$ cannot be for every possible $t_1$. The "consequently" just means: "It follows, that $\dots$". But since there is no $t_1$ such that $\varphi(t_1) \neq 0$, it follows $v(\varphi(t)) = v(\varphi(t_0)) = 0$ for all $t$, which means $\dot{\varphi} = 0$, i. e. $\varphi$ is constant. Therefore, the uniqueness if proven for the case that $x_0$ is an equilibrium position. Now, everything is shown.